# js loading page message not working on php file

Tags: php, javascript, html

Merry Christmas guys,

I found a code that displays a loading message using a gif. It uses the onLoad="init()" in the body tag. It works fine on an HTML file but it doesn't when the file is in PHP. Do I need to change anything in here or this just won't work in a PHP file? here's the code:

```
<body onLoad="init()">
   <div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center; top:300px;">
   <img src="loading.gif" border=0></div>

   <script>
     var ld=(document.all);
     var ns4=document.layers;
     var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;
     var ie4=document.all;
     if (ns4)
   ld=document.loading;
     else if (ns6)
   ld=document.getElementById("loading").style;
     else if (ie4)
   ld=document.all.loading.style;

  function init() {
     if(ns4){ld.visibility="hidden";}
     else if (ns6||ie4) ld.display="none";
  }
  </script>

  <?php

  include('simple_html_dom.php');

  $html= new simple_html_dom();

  $html->load_file('urls.html');

  $element = $html->find("p");
  $size = count($element);

  for($i=0; $i <= $size ;$i++){

printinfo($element[$i]->innertext);
  }

  function printinfo($url){

$page= new simple_html_dom();

$page->load_file($url);

$arr = $page->find("title");
echo $arr[0]->innertext." = ";  

$arr = $page->find('.altroute-rcol');
echo $arr[0]->innertext."<br>";
  }
  ?>

  </body>
```

**EDIT:** What my php code does is parse some code and displays the info that I needed. The code works fine, depending on how many urls that I need to parse it could take up to 30 secs that's why I needed a loading message.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you post the `init` function?

Comment: There is no reason this shouldn't work if it is being output correctly from the php script.  Can you post your PHP code exactly as it is?

Comment: Change the onLoad="init()" to onLoad="javascript:init()" see if that works. And change your script tag to <script type="text/javascript"

Comment: hey guys I added the rest of the code. Thanks.

Comment: @William- It didn't do anything. Thanks.

Comment: So you want the javascript to start before the php finishes generating the page?

Comment: I wonder what dark part of the internet was this script dug out from... NS4? Seriously?

Comment: @ KThompson - yes. That's right.

Comment: @William that's a funny one...

Comment: @eggman20 - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Sorry about that guys.... will work on that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP responses don't start loading until they're finished processing. Where a browser will display an HTML page progressively, PHP pages are typically displayed all at once.

You can force a PHP response to display progressively by calling `flush()` at the point you want to send a partial response, but support varies between servers.

Try putting `flush();` before you parse your XML and let us know if that helps.